# Text in speech bubble Blender v.2.81a

Tags: 2d

I'm doing a school project and I'm drawing a 2D animation in the latest blender version. I drew a speech bubble. Is there a way to create text inside the speech bubble with blender. I don't want to draw it because it's too messy. Is there a way to type text in the 2D animation? I'm new to this program.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange. Should the text have some animation, so that it looks like it gets hand-drawn, or just appear at once? The last one would be waaay easier ^^

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a text-object, switch to object mode.

[image: switch to object mode]

Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and select the "Text"-option, to add a new text-object.

Because the new text-object is rotated by default, you may not see it from your perspective, so rotate it on the x-Axis by 90°. (<kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>90</kbd>)

[image: rotation of added text]

The text can be altered if you have it selected and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, to enter edit mode, then change your text as in any text editor. Press tab again, to exit edit mode. Other text settings like the font can be found in the right side panel.